# javafx slider thumb move

Tags: java, javafx, slider

I need move Thumb on slider only to special value on track.
How it's going on: if click by mouse on JavaFX Slider - first point (Thumb) moving to place where was click, then moving to new position. But I need move thumb only to new position.
I'm using

```
amountSldr.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {});
```

and

```
amountSldr.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, event -> {
    amountSldr.valueProperty().set(newVal);
});
```

May be someone know how can I do it? Thank you alot!!!

Comment: How do you specify the "new position"? You can configure the slider to snap to the ticks only, if that helps - see [`javafx.scene.control.Slider.setSnapToTicks(true);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#setSnapToTicks-boolean-).

Comment: I have track with values from 100 to 3000. For example, slider's thumb right now staying on value 1200. I click to the right of thumb at the end of track, and calculating new position (must be 1200 + 100 = 1300). Then thumb moving to place where was click and then to 1300. But thumb must move only to 1300. May be anybody know how to move thumb correctly?